# AttributeError: type object 'Cliente' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

This is my first project using Python.

I'm encountering a problem while displaying the values ​​in my table.

> AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'query'

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import os
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref,sessionmaker


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///banco.db', echo=True)
db = declarative_base()


class Cliente(db):
    __tablename__ = 'cliente'

    _idCliente = Column(Integer, primary_key =True, autoincrement = True)
    nmCliente = Column (String)

    def __init__ (self, nmCliente):
        self.nmCliente = nmCliente

db.metadata.create_all(engine)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/cadastros/cliente")
def cadastroCliente():
    return render_template ("cadastroCliente.html")

@app.route("/cadastrar/cliente", methods=['GET','POST'])
def cadastrarCliente():
    if request.method == "POST":
        nmCliente = request.form.get("nmCliente")

        if nmCliente:
            c = Cliente(nmCliente)
            db.session.add(c)
            db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for("cadastroCliente"))

@app.route("/consulta/cliente")
def consulta():
    cliente = Cliente.query.all()
    return render_template("consultaClientes.html", cliente = cliente)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Python 2.7, what should i change?
I followed some tutorials and it worked

Answer (score 5):

You query like that when using Flask-SQLAlchemy (from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy)

In your code, you will need to use session, because you are using SQLAlchemy. So import session maker like this

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
```

Then below `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///banco.db', echo=True)`

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Then do your query using session

```
cliente = session.query(Cliente).all()
```

You can see the pros and cons of using Flask-SQLAlchemy (more integrated with flask) [here](http://derrickgilland.com/posts/demystifying-flask-sqlalchemy/) and see you would want to go with it

Comment: Thanks Moses, it worked.
But when i refresh my page return: 

"ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 15436 and this is thread id 14240. [SQL: u'SELECT cliente."_idCliente" AS "cliente__idCliente", cliente."nmCliente" AS "cliente_nmCliente" \nFROM cliente'] [parameters: [{}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)"

Comment: SQLite by default prohibits the usage of a single connection in more than one thread. just add connect_args={'check_same_thread': False} parameter to your engine variable like `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///banco.db',connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}, echo=True)`

Comment: For this very reason you should just use Flask-SQLAlchemy with Flask, since it ties the (thread-local) session to a request's life cycle and you don't need to play fast and loose with SQLite threading support. Getting it all right on your own is possible, of course: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/

Comment: Is there a way to use `Model.query` style as Flask-SQLAlchemy provided?